# How do I evaluate the following Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

The integral is $$\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a(1+x^2)^m+b(1+x^2)^{m-2}x^2}},$$
where $m, a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that the integral is definitely convergent. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: any own ideas? what have u tried?

Comment: I was looking for a change of variable, $x=\tan\theta$, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Why are $a$ and $b$ important unless there is a typo of course.

Answer (score 1):

- The integral converges for $m>1$.
- If the integrand has a pole on $(0,\infty)$, i.e., if its denominator vanishes for some $x>0$, see [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).
- In particular, for $m=2$, if the quartic polynomial can be factored into a product of two coprime quadratics, then, for positive values of *A* and *B*, we have the following results, in 
   terms of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral):

> $$\begin{align}
> \int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\Big(x^2+A\Big)\Big(x^2+B\Big)}}~&=~\frac1{\sqrt{+A}}~K\bigg(\sqrt{1-\frac BA}~\bigg)
> \\\\\
> \int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\Big(x^2-A\Big)\Big(x^2+B\Big)}}~&=~\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-A}}~\overline K\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac BA}~\bigg)
> \\\\
> \int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\Big(x^2-A\Big)\Big(x^2-B\Big)}}~&=~\frac1{\sqrt{-A}}~K\bigg(\sqrt{1-\frac BA}~\bigg)+\frac2{\sqrt B}~\Re\bigg[K\bigg(\sqrt{\frac AB}~\bigg)\bigg]
> \end{align}$$